# Renderer Efficiency

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Ok, I have a renderer class which has all kinds of special functions called by the rest of the program:

- DrawBoxFilled
- DrawText
- DrawLine
- About 30 more...

Each of these functions calls glBegin/glEnd separably, which I know can be very inefficiently(its even deprecated).  So anyways, I am planning a total rewrite of the renderer and I need to know the most efficient ways to set up the functions so that when something calls it, it draws it all at once, or whatever else it needs to do so it will run ***most*** efficiently.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does your application do? What does it need to draw? Why are you drawing text and lines individually?

Comment: The program is set in a series of states.  Each state needs to draw different objects like Text, Boxes, or something else.  Like Singleton<Renderer>::get().drawText("Yea...", 10, 10);

Comment: And how often does the scene chance? When are objects added or removed? Per frame, or only when changing state (which I assume is somewhat rare)

Comment: Each state has an update function that gets called every frame.  The update functions are where the drawing functions are called.

Comment: But what is updated in each frame?

Comment: The state is updated each frame, and then the state calls all of the drawing functions each frame.

Comment: So as long as I am in the same state, the scene stays the same?

Comment: No, each state has its own logic, like an editor state or a login state.

Answer (score 6):

The efficient way to render is generally to use VBO's (vertex buffer objects) to store your vertex data, but that is only really meaningful if you are rendering (mostly) static data.

Without knowing more about what your application is supposed to render, it's hard to say how you should structure it. But ideally, you should never draw individual primitives, but rather draw the contents (a subset) of a vertexbuffer.

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way is not to expose such low-level methods at all. Instead, what you want to do is build a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph), which is a data structure that contains a representation of the entire scene. You update the scene graph in your "update" method, then render the whole thing in one go in your "render" method.

Another, slightly different approach is to re-build the entire scene graph each frame. This has the advantage that once the scene graph is composed, it doesn't change. So you can call your "render" method on another thread while your "update" method is going through and constructing the scene for the *next* frame at the same time.

Many of the more advanced effects are simply not possible without a complete scene graph. You can't do shadow mapping, for instance (which requires you to render the scene multiple times from a different angle), you can't do deferred rendering, it also makes anything which relies on sorted draw order (e.g. alpha-blending) very difficult.

From your method names, it looks like you're working in 2D, so while shadow mapping is probably not high on your feature list, alpha-blending deferred rendering might be.